# Copy Paste Between Excels over Remote Desktop Services

Tags: microsoft-excel, remote-desktop, copy-paste, clipboard, unicode

Currently a number of our users have an issue whereby they attempt to copy data from excel on their computer and paste it to excel on a terminal server.

If users use standard `paste` (i.e. `ctrl`+`v`) an area the size of the copied data is selected in the destination sheet, but no data is sent.

If instead users use `paste special`, `unicode text`, the paste functionality works as one would expect.

User's Computer

- Windows XP / Windows 7
- Office 2003 / Office 2007

TS Client

- Windows Server 2008 R2 SE
- Office 2007 Pro Plus SP3

The TS Excel is presented to the user using RemoteApp via TS Web.

The paste special solution gives us a work around, but I'd like to fix the root cause to save users this headache.  Does anyone know what may be causing this / how I might be able to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with the TS Web rather than Excel, but it is fairly straightforward to build a macro to automate a `Paste Special` operation and bind it to a keyboard shortcut.

There is a tutorial here that walks you through [creating custom keyboard shortcuts with macros in Excel](http://exceltactics.com/make-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-using-macros/). It is set up to `Paste Values`, but if you need to tailor specifics to `Unicode Text`, it should be a simple tweak.